# Using 'rendered' with Dynamic Visualforce Component

Tags: visualforce, dynamic

I am considering using Dynamic Visualforce components for a project, however I have hit a potential showstopper with my approach.

If you consider the following (valid) Visualforce:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered='{!oppt.StageName=="Closed Won"}'>
<!-- some content -->
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I would like to replicate that in Apex as follows:

```
Component.Apex.OutputPanel panel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
panel.rendered = '{!oppt.StageName=="Closed Won"}';
```

However, the compiler rightfully complains that rendered is a Boolean and I'm trying to assing a String.

I guess its probably a long shot, but does anyone know if there is anyway of achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an apex variable?

Comment: Because that would mean that I need to know at design time the condition which gives me true of false...which unfortunately I don't (I provided the above example to illustrate a point). I suspect what I'm trying to achieve is too dynamic but I wondered if I was missing a trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "expressions" attribute to assign an expression such as `rendered`.

```
panel.expressions.rendered = '{!oppt.StageName=="Closed Won"}';
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much @sfdcfox - I knew about setting expressions.value but not other attributes such as rendered. Thanks again.

Comment: Any attribute that accepts an expression will be visible in expressions. This means that ID, for example, doesn't have an expression, but ones like URL, headerClass, headerValue, etc, do.

Comment: Cool...don't suppose you happen to know if by chance you can access those properties dynamically too?

Comment: I just experimented with this, and yes, it works immediately if you read the value. For example, I was able to get this to work:         `Component.Apex.outputText text = new Component.apex.outputText();
        text.expressions.rendered = '{!1=2}';
        System.assertEquals(false, text.rendered);`

Comment: Ah, sorry - thats not quite what I meant, I meant something like text.expressions.put('rendered','{!1=2}') - don't think its possible having tried a few things

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's not that expressive. You have to use hard references to the attributes.

Comment: Hi Phil, lots of attributes can be added using expressions. Sometimes are redundant like in the case of the output text and some other doesn't work like this case, or repeat... However theres is one that I've been not able to add yet: styleClass, did you?.By the moment I'm injecting HTML using escape=false on the markups and I set up the style on the HTML.